# Offline upload photo to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Include the facebook api file and set the appId and appSecret

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); 
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Uploaded'); 
$args['access_token'] = 'access token'; 
$filename = 'image.jpg' $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($filename); 
$result = $facebook->api('/' . $fuid . '/photos', 'post', $args);
```

My current app lets the user authorise off-line updates and I store the access_token, fuid. and I can succesfully post to a users wall when they are offline.but when i upload the photo to server it does not work.
Can any body tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Photos uploads is not the same as wall posts.  They are two different permissions.

This is your workaround. Wall posts can contain a url to a website page that has the photo on it with proper og meta tags correctly specified.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks For the answer? Actually my question is that can i upload the photo of user wall if i have the facebook userid of the user and user has allow the all permission of my app.Can i do it without login the user.

Comment: "Can i do it without login the user." - No, the user must login for your app to have permissions to post to their wall.